# Subscription to QuantumLeap doesnt work Orion Context Broker

Tags: fiware

I continued with the project, but now i have encountered a problem with a subscription to quantumleap, here is the subscription:

```bash
curl -iX POST 'http://localhost:1026/v2/subscriptions/' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Fiware-Service: myClassRoom'  -H 'Fiware-ServicePath: /' -d '{
  "description": "Notify QuantumLeap when the temperature changes",
  "subject": {
    "entities": [{ "idPattern": "SensTemp.*"}],
    "condition": {
      "attrs": [ "temperature"]
    }
  },
  "notification": {
    "http": {
      "url": "http://quantum-leap:8668/v2/notify"
    },
    "attrs": ["temperature"],
    "metadata": ["dateCreated", "dateModified"]
  },
  "expires": "2025-02-03T08:00:00.00Z",
  "throttling": 5
}'
```

And it gives me a positive response like this

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
Location: /v2/subscriptions/62e3a39b8aa7c71c4b3e6c05
Fiware-Correlator: 0b597668-0f1e-11ed-b343-0242ac120005
Date: Fri, 29 Jul 2022 09:08:43 GMT
```

But when i check for the subscriptions on Orion context Broker it doesn't exists:

```bash
curl -X GET   --url 'http://localhost:1026/v2/subscriptions/
```

I get the response `[]`.  Why it doesn't see the subscription?
It also shows on the server screen that is created, but when i want to check for the subscriptions, they don't exist `

```
srdjan-orion-1         | time=2022-07-29T09:18:31.342Z | lvl=INFO | corr=69e57bcc-0f1f-11ed-abf0-0242ac120005 | trans=1659082790-602-00000000170 | from=172.18.0.1 | srv=myclassroom | subsrv=/ | comp=Orion | op=logTracing.cpp[148]:logInfoRequestWithPayload | msg=Request received: POST /v2/subscriptions/, request payload (377 bytes): { "description": "Notify QuantumLeap when the temperature changes", "subject": { "entities": [ { "idPattern": "SensTemp" } ], "condition": { "attrs": [ "temperature" ] } }, "notification": { "http": { "url": "http://quantum-leap:8668/v2/notify" }, "attrs": [ "temperature" ], "metadata": ["dateCreated", "dateModified"] },"expires": "2025-02-03T08:00:00.00Z", "throttling": 5 }, response code: 201
```

Comment: I want to connect to the quantumleap so the data could be passed to crateDB and get visualized in the Grafana... But the subscription doesn't work...

Comment: Why it doesnt work? Can someone give me a hint please?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a subscription on a tenant called `myClassRoom` using `fiware-service`:

```
'http://localhost:1026/v2/subscriptions/' ... -H 'Fiware-Service: myClassRoom'
```

You are checking the result without supplying `fiware-service` and therefore checking the **default** tenant.

```
'http://localhost:1026/v2/subscriptions/'
```

No subscriptions have been created on the **default** tenant, so an empty array is returned.